Ursina "panda3d.core.NodePath" has no attribute to "uvs"
I'm trying to recreate Minecraft in Ursina engine (python), but when I created the inventory spots, there was an AttributeError. I tried to make a set_texture function in a class called Item. This is my code:
def set_texture(self):
    # Use dictionary to access uv co-ords.
    # minerals is from another module I was making
    # it is a dictionary that stores all the block types' x and y
    uu = minerals[self.blockType][0]
    uv = minerals[self.blockType][1] 
    basemod = load_model("block.obj", use_deepcopy=True)
    cb = copy(basemod.uvs)
    del cb[:-33]
    self.model.uvs = [Vec2(uu, uv) + u for u in cb]
    self.model.generate()
    self.rotation_z = 180

In case anybody ask, the class init code is:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = "quad"
    # Hotspot.scalar is from another class, it works without any 
        problem
    self.scale_x = Hotspot.scalar * 0.9
    self.scale_y = self.scale_x
    self.color = color.white
    self.texture = load_texture("texture_atlas_3.png")
    self.texture_scale *= 64 / self.texture.width

The error was:
  File "c:\Users\alber\OneDrive\Documents\Dev\Minecraft\inventory_sys.py", line 54, in set_texture
    self.model.uvs = [Vec2(uu, uv) + u for u in cb]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'panda3d.core.NodePath' object has no attribute 'uvs'

I tried to import copy from copy and surround basemod.uvs with it. I also  tried to add use_deepcopy=True in the load_model function. For your information, I imported * from ursina. The only problem is the AttributeError. I also tried creating e = Empty(model=basemod) and then replace cb with cb=copy(e.model.uvs). Any luck fixing the problem?

what is self.model ? where do you create it? Documentation for panda3d.core.NodePath doesn't have .uvs and maybe you should create own class and add .uvs

I edited the question so it contains the class def init(self) code

I solved the problem myself! I replaced self.model = "quad" into: load_model("quad", use_deepcopy=True).
